# Identification of non-latin characters in android

Tags: android, keycode, onkeydown, non-latin

I'm trying to get code of pressed key in my android activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    char ch = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

but the keyCode does not depend on keyboard layout.
For latin characters it's working ok, but for non-latin characters, e.g. "П","Э","б"(russian) keyCode returns code of latin symbol from pressed key. Seems, that keycode depends on key only, not keyboard layout.

This way key with latin symbol G will return keyCode of G for every keyboard layout.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the KeyCharacterMap as described here? See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html

[Can't get meta state from Android KeyEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959160/cant-get-meta-state-from-android-keyevent)

Comment: keyCharacterMap waits for integer keyCode. 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        KeyCharacterMap km = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.FULL);
        setNotification("" + km.getDisplayLabel(keyCode));
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

But this keyCode is same for all keyboard layouts

Comment: meta state is used for alt, ctrl, caps etc keys, not for keyboards layouts (languages)